# Pass current page URL and Title in contact form

Tags: javascript, php, html, simplemodal

I've implemented 'Simplemodal Contact Form(SMCF)', when form pops up and user send message to my mail,  I want to automatically include a link to the page they are on and title of the particular page in the email, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to grab the url for the page they are on.

I'm receiving a URL but it's 'contact.php', where as I want the URL of HTML page

Can anyone help me out on this? Also Please let me know if you need further clarification.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: look into `$_SERVER`

Comment: You don't need JavaScript at all if you have PHP. As Cayce K suggests you can use $_SERVER to know where the request came from (full URL). As for the page title, well, you are generating that yourself so you could also send it over or fetch it from where ever it is.

Comment: I'm using this code for page URL :  // Set absolute_url
 
    $absolute_url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
  
    $body .= "From URL: $absolute_url\n\n";

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can get the url of the current page as

```
document.URL
```

You can get the url from the main page and before calling the pop, pass it as a parameter to the pop function javascript.
In further assistance let me know about the form pop code.

Comment: I was going to say `location.href`, but I think `document.URL` is more elegant.

Comment: I've already tried with onload=document.getElementById('location').value = window.location.href; in body tag of the page but it passed the same page URL(contact.php). I'm not very much familiar with PHP code, I'm following the code in the contact.php.

Comment: If you write document.getElementById('location').value = window.location.href in the contach.php, you will be getting contact.php. I would recommend to call document.URL from the parent window, and pass the value to the contact.php through javascript. Please let me know how your triggering contact.php